# reledpar Wrap text paragraphs but sync at page break

Tags: page-breaking, reledpar, parallel-texts

I have a very large Hebrew doc and translation. I'd like the Hebrew text to be much larger with a small translation on the side. I can put all the sentences into "paragraphs" for synchronization but there should be a way to wrap paragraphs and run an if loop where if one column is the first paragraph of a new page then the synchronized paragraph should also start on that page. As the text is now it would take a lot longer to divide several sentences into paragraphs. 
  The image below illustrates what I'd like. Ignore the highlights. The English text sync with the Greek but only at the page break. So you need a dynamic system to inform the texts when to sync. I don't think any of the packages do this. 
[image: this Greek nt illustrates what I'd like. Each pages is synced to the English translation on the side but on the page none of the verse align]

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)). They are often necessary; but in the case of non-Latin alphabets, it is even harder for others to recreate the problem/issue you would like addressed.

Comment: Are you using the paracol package?

Comment: Im happy to try paracol but none of the packages seem to do what I want. Also the Hebrew text is not an issue. If you can recreate it in all English I could  figure out how to use it.

Comment: I am not sur to understand why reldpar does not work for you.

Comment: So the difference between the above picture and what reledpar does is at the point to synchronisation. In the above photo the verses wrap and don't each start new lines. But when there's a new page it syncs with the next verse. Maybe reledpar does do this but from what I've seen each paragraph must be a synced location and therefore can't wrap and thus no dynamic/logic dependant sync points.